# What is the estimated file size of Firebase SDK?

Tags: filesize

The developer developing my iOS app is saying that the Firebase SDK is adding a substantial amount of file size to the app. Is this true?

What is the typical range of file size added to an iOS app that uses Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty late for this answer, However, it might be helpful for someone who is currently integrating Firebase.

With Firebase 5

Our final ipa size shows an increase of about **~13MB.**

Note: Once released to AppStore, there will be a variation on download size as the app will be thinned based on client device and architecture.

Reason:

I found that pod 'Firebase/Core' downloads other dependencies listed below :

- Firebase (5.20.2)
- FirebaseAnalytics (5.8.1)
- FirebaseCore (5.4.1)
- FirebaseInstanceID (3.8.1)
- GoogleAppMeasurement (5.8.1)
- GoogleUtilities (5.8.0)
- nanopb (0.3.901)